# Corrupted display in Qt/OpenGL widget

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, maya

I am currently developing a Maya c++ plugin, and want to display an OpenGL window using Qt (QGLWidget) with 2 simple shapes. However the display is strange:
[image]

The code is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <QGLWidget>

class GLWidget :public QGLWidget
{
public:
    GLWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~GLWidget(){};
protected:
    virtual void initializeGL();
    virtual void resizeGL( int width, int height );
    virtual void paintGL();
};

GLWidget::GLWidget(QWidget *parent) : QGLWidget(parent)
{
}

void GLWidget::initializeGL() {
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
}

void GLWidget::resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    updateGL();
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();

    glTranslatef(3.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    glVertex3d(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnd();
}
```

Anything I need to do to have a proper display ?

Comment: The QGLWidget is a Qt widget aimed for OpenGL, so it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was linked to the fact that a QGLWidget cannot be added to a QGraphicsScene. I had to go via a QGridLayout

Comment: I wonder: Can you still interact with Maya while your plug-in is showing its window?